# How to create a JS object and append it to an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the following data :

```
const data=
{
"1": [
    {
        "sales_project_id": 5,
        "sales_project_name": "name",
        "sales_project_est_rev": "123.00",
        "project_status": {
            "id": 1,
            "label": "Start",
            "description": null
        }
    },
    {
        "sales_project_id": 6,
        "sales_project_name": "name2",
        "sales_project_est_rev": "123.00",
        "project_status": {
            "id": 1,
            "label": "Start",
            "description": null
        }
    }
],
"2": [],
"4": []
```

}

These data are grouped in my backend based on their Status , in this case im only showing 2 status , but they are dynamic and can be anything the user defines.

What i wish to do is to transform the above data into the format below :

```
const data = 
{
        columns: [
          {
            id: // id of status here,
            title: //label of status here,
            cards: [
              {
                id : //sales_project_id here,
                title: //sales_project_name here,
              },
            ]
          },
          {
            id: // id of status here,
            title: //label of status here,
            cards: [
              {
                id : //sales_project_id here,
                title: //sales_project_name here,
              },
            ]
          }
        ]}
```

My guess would be to iterate over the data , however i am pretty unfamiliar with doing so , would appreciate someone's help!

Here is what i could come up with so far:

```
        const array = []
    Object.keys(a).map(function(keyName, keyIndex) {
        a[keyName].forEach(element => {
            #creating an object of the columns array here 

        });
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

after some trial and error , manage to accomplish this , however , im not sure if this is a good method to do so.

```
        Object.keys(projects).map(function(keyName, keyIndex) {
        // use keyName to get current key's name
        // and a[keyName] to get its value
        var project_object = {}
        project_object['id'] = projects[keyName][0].id
        project_object['title'] =  projects[keyName][0].label
        project_object['description'] =  projects[keyName][0].description
        console.log( projects[keyName][1])
        var card_array = []
        projects[keyName][1].forEach(element => {
            var card = {}
            card["id"] = element.sales_project_id
            card["title"] = element.sales_project_name
            card["description"] = element.sales_project_est_rev
            card_array.push(card)
        });
        project_object["cards"] = card_array
        array.push(project_object)
      })
```

Im basically manipulating some the scope of the variables inorder to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

I'd just do this. Get the values of `data` using `Object.values(data)` and then use `reduce` to accumulate the desired result

```js
const data=
{
"1": [
    {
        "sales_project_id": 5,
        "sales_project_name": "name",
        "sales_project_est_rev": "123.00",
        "project_status": {
            "id": 1,
            "label": "Start",
            "description": null
        }
    },
    {
        "sales_project_id": 6,
        "sales_project_name": "name2",
        "sales_project_est_rev": "123.00",
        "project_status": {
            "id": 1,
            "label": "Start",
            "description": null
        }
    }
],
"2": [],
"4": []
};

const a = Object.values(data)

let res =a.reduce((acc, elem)=>{
 elem.forEach((x)=>{
   var obj = {
       id : x.project_status.id,
       title : x.project_status.label,
       cards : [{
           id: x.sales_project_id,
           title: x.sales_project_name
        }]

  }
    acc.columns.push(obj);
  })
 return acc
},{columns: []});

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

See my solution, I use Object.keys like you, then I use reduce:

```
const newData = { columns: Object.keys(data).map((item) => {
  return data[item].reduce((acc,rec) => { 
    if (typeof acc.id === 'undefined'){
      acc = { id: rec.project_status.id, title: rec.project_status.label, ...acc }
    }
    return {...acc, cards: [...acc.cards, { id:rec.sales_project_id, title:rec.sales_project_name}]}
  }, {cards:[]})
})}
```

See full example in playground: https://jscomplete.com/playground/s510194

Comment: Why not? My result like your, but I just return empty arrays for 2 and 4 items